# Get to the view controller that pushed the visible view controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app that has a `UINavigationController` that pushes a `UITabBarController` into view. This `UITabBarController` has four tabs, one of which shows a custom `UIViewController`, an instance of `EventInformationViewController`. A button in this custom view controller in turn pushes another custom view controller `EventRatingAddViewController` into view. An action in this view controller should invoke a method in the `EventInformationViewController` instance. The following code makes the app crash instead:

```
// get the index of the visible VC on the stack
int myIindex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.navigationController.visibleViewController];
// get a reference to the previous VC
EventInformationViewController *prevVC = (EventInformationViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:myIindex - 1];
[prevVC performSelector:@selector(rateCurrentEvent:)];
```

I thought that the viewControllers property kept an array of all VCs on the navigation stack, so the index the currently visible one minus one should point to the VC that pushed the currently visible VC into view. Rather, it seems to point to my `UITabBarController`:

```
-[UITabBarController rateCurrentEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What is up with that and more importantly, how do I get a pointer to the VC that pushed the currently visisble VC into view?

EDIT: I ended up creating a delegate protocol for the `EventRatingAddViewController` and assigning the `EventInformationViewController` as delegate. This works well - still I am thinking there should be a way to access the pushing VC through the navigation stack.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should use `.topViewController` instead of `.visibleViewController` as the latter could also be a modally presented view controller that has nothing to do with your navigation controller stack!

Comment: Have you tried logging `myIindex` and the index of that UITabBarController you get?

Comment: Good point about the topViewController. Doesn't make a difference in this case, as I have no modal VCs in my app. The visible VC gets index 2, the UITabBarController 1.

Comment: Why are you showing a tab bar controller with just 1 tab? Why not just present a view controller by pushing it onto the stack or modally

Comment: @rickharrisson -> the UITabBarController has four tabs, it's only this one under consideration that has a VC that pushes a new VC onto the stack.

Comment: edited the question to make clear that the UITabBarController has more tabs than the one under consideration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that that `UITabBarController` did indeed push your current view controller, but that what you are looking for is the view controller of one of this `UITabBarController`'s tabs, the view controller that was visible in the `UITabBarController` at the time this `UITabBarController` pushed your view controller on the navigation stack. Possibly this `UITabBarController` pushed your view controller on the stack, because it was told to do so by the visible tab's view controller, so it would be something like this: `[self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController];`.

The way to find out what view controller was shown in the `UITabBarController` at the time your view controller was pushed on the stack, is to use the `.selectedViewController` property, so that would result in something like this:

```
// get the index of the visible VC on the stack
int currentVCIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.navigationController.topViewController];
// get a reference to the previous VC
UITabBarController *prevVC = (UITabBarController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentVCIndex - 1];
// get the VC shown by the previous VC
EventInformationViewController *prevShownVC = (EventInformationViewController *)prevVC.selectedViewController;
[prevShownVC performSelector:@selector(rateCurrentEvent:)];
```